# Inserting only one value of a pair

Tags: c++, stl

Is it possible to insert only one value in a `std::pair`?
I have a vector of pairs that I need to fill members of pairs separately in different loops. I can use temporary variables or use a dummy value (like 0) for the other member while inserting the actual one.

```
std::vector<std::pair<typeA, typeB>> ports;
ports.emplace_back(actual_value, 0);
```

Isn't there any cleaner way to do that without inserting a dummy value (0)?

`emplace_back()` needs both members of pairs.

Comment: You could consider `std::pair< std::optional<typeA>, std::optional<typeB> >`.  But an instance of your `std::pair<typeA, typeB>` must hold a constructed `typeA` and `typeB`.

Comment: Also consider using two `std::vector` independently, then joining into pairs.

Comment: Why are you using a `std::pair` if you don't need both?

Comment: @KevinWoodward Yes, it is another way.

Comment: @CaseyI need both, but both values are not ready at the same time and I need to pair them.

Comment: @DrewDormann It actually did the trick and worked perfectly. I used `std::nullopt` for the element I didn't want to assign it in the current loop. Thanks!

Comment: `std::optional` has a fair bit of overhead; if you have "impossible values" there's not much wrong with initialising with those instead of using the optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider

```
std::pair< std::optional<typeA>, std::optional<typeB> >
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^
```

Wherever you don't want to store a value, store `{}` or `std::nullopt`.

It would increase the size of your type by one `bool` (plus padding)

But an instance of your `std::pair<typeA, typeB>` **must** hold a constructed `typeA` and `typeB`.